# Hash Tables program crashes

Tags: c, hashtable

I wonder if I'm doing something wrong in my program.

I manage to create a `HashTable` but when I send it through parameter to my `displayingList()` function, it crashes.

**source.c** (contains my functions):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "header.h"

#define MAX 255

int countLetters(char myStr[])
{
    int myLen = strlen(myStr), i;
    int wordLen = 0;

    for (i = 0 ; i < myLen; ++i)
    {
        wordLen += (int)(myStr[i]);
    }

    return (wordLen%256);
}

void populateList(NodeT *T[255], char myStr[])
{
    NodeT *p, *q;

    p = (NodeT *)malloc(sizeof(NodeT));
    strcpy (p->key, myStr);

    int myPos = countLetters(myStr);

    if(T[myPos] == NULL)
    {
        p->next = NULL;
        T[myPos] = p;
    }
    else
    {
        q = T[myPos];
        p->next = q;
        T[myPos] = p;
    }

}

void displayList(NodeT *T[255])
{
    int i;
    NodeT *p;

    for(i = 0 ; i < 255; ++i)
    {
        if(T[i] != NULL)
        {
            printf("Index: %d - Data:", i);

            p = T[i];
            while(p != 0)
            {
                printf("%s, ", p->key); // HERE IT CRASHES.
                p = p->next;
            }

            printf("\n");
        }     
    }

}
```

**main.c** (contains the `int main()`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header.h"


int main(void)
{
    NodeT *T[255];
    int n, i;

    printf("Give no. of elements:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    fflush(stdin);
    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
    {
        char name[100];    
        gets(name);

        populateList(T, name);
    }

    displayList(T);

    return 0;
}
```

**header.h** (and my header):

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

typedef struct cell
{
     char key[100];
     struct cell *next;

}NodeT;

int countLetters(char myStr[]);
void populateList(NodeT *T[], char myStr[]);
void displayList(NodeT *T[]);

#endif // HEADER_H
```

I tried to see what exactly happens with debugger and it seems that when I send `T[]` list to `displayList()` function, actually it doesn't have the same structure as it has in `main.c`.

**ISSUE:** the insertion works fine, but when I try to display my list (on each index) it crashes.

Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does it crash? Run it under a debugger.

Comment: Updated. When I try to call : `p->key`;

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but try writing `NodeT *T[255] = {0};`.

Comment: In the input, are there lines longer than 100 chars?

Comment: No, only strings up to 15-20 chars.

Comment: Also, you should init the array with 255 NULL pointers. Like this, it just stores random pointers, which is not a problem in populate, but in displaylist you try to use those pointers pointing to random addresses in memory.

Comment: ... and either also initialise `char name[100] = "";` or test the outcome of `gets()`.

Comment: Well, that is problem after all in populate as well, I wonder why it doesnt crash there.

Comment: @alk cant really test the outcome of gets, should use fgets

Comment: @BuellaGábor, pointer values are used in populate, not objects they point to.

Comment: Yes, and those pointer values are not initialized

Comment: Sure you can `gets()` returns `NULL` on error. However I fully agree not using it, but use `fgets()` @BuellaGábor

Comment: But also, I wonder why the List T doesn't have the same structure as it has in `int main()`?. In watch I can see all indexes in `int main()` but in `displayList()` it looks like it is just a cell (NodeT)

Comment: Well, gets only returns errors it manages to detect, but im sure there are thousands of SO questions about it.

Comment: @fiskerXO, if you mean something like output in a debugger, than it's because compiler ignores `255` in list of parameters and debugger sees only `T**`.

Comment: @alk OP inits key using strcpy, that part is fine, there is nothing more to init about it.

Comment: My bad, you are correct! @BuellaGábor deleting ..

Comment: As a sidenote to OP: in countletters, if you use unsigned char, and your system has 8 bits CHAR ( likely ) , instead of int for wordLen, you wont need to do wordLen%256 . Integer overflow does it for you automagically.

Comment: shouldnt p be malloced in displaylist func?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible solution is to declare the `NodeT *T[255]` global. However it isn't the best practice at all.